# if there is no post data redirect back to the registration page

Tags: php

I have a form:

```
<form id='register' action='http://mydev/test/register' onsubmit="return validateForm()" method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'>
<fieldset>
<legend><br/>Create An Account</legend><br/>
<input type='hidden' name='submitted' id='submitted' value='1'/>
<!--<label for='username' >Username*: </label>
<input type='text' name='username' id='username' maxlength="50" /><br/><br/></br/>-->
<label for='email' >Email Address*:</label>
<input type='text' name='email' id='email' maxlength="50" /><br/><br/>
<label for='password'>Password:</label>
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" size="32" /><br><br>
<label for='retype_password'>Re-Enter Password:</label>
<input type="password" name="password-check" id="password-check" value="" size="32" /><br><br>
<label for='cpassword' >&zwnj;</label>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
</fieldset>
</form>
```

I than have my action page which sends an activation link to their email:

```
$shopper = new Shopper();
$shopper->set_email($_POST['email']);
$shopper->set_username($_POST['email']);
if($shopper->create($_POST['password']))
    {
    $message = "<br>User created<br>" . "An activation code has been sent<br>";
    $token = $shopper->request_activation();
    }
    else
        {
        $message = "Could not create user<br>";
        }
```

My question is... if there is no post data and they somehow end up on the register.php page.. just redirect them back to the new_registration.php page.

I know I should user `header("location:../../new_registration.php");`

I'm just a bit confused on how to check for the missing post data?

Should i be using `empty`?

I ended up using:

```
    if (empty($_POST['email']['password'])) {
    header('location:http://myjeromesdev/test/new_registration');
}
    else {
$shopper = new Shopper();
$shopper->set_email($_POST['email']);
$shopper->set_username($_POST['email']);
if($shopper->create($_POST['password']))
    {
    $message = "<br>User created<br>" . "An activation code has been sent<br>";
    $token = $shopper->request_activation();
    }
    else
        {
        $message = "Could not create user<br>";
        } 

}
?>
<p>
<?php 
echo $message 
?></p>
```

Comment: You could check `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` to determine if a redirect is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use empty, but also you should check if the received $_POST data is what you are waiting for.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(!empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['password']))
 {
      $shopper = new Shopper();
      $shopper->set_email($_POST['email']);
      $shopper->set_username($_POST['email']);
      ...
 }
 else
 {
  //Your redirect
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

u can use isset and set name at submit (not set name is also ok) u can use one name of you input

see this code

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>


if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    //code is have 
}else{
    header('URL');
}

if you want if all post is setted u can use AND
isset($_POST['password']) && isset($_POST['email']) and so on
```

hope this answer help you